# How to create soap request template using java

Tags: java, wsdl, wsdl2java, wsdl.exe, java2wsdl

I want to create soap template for give WSDL(the WSDL will change).I want to create a soap template like SoupUI.Steps I need

1.User will give the give the URL

2.Parse the WSDL

3.Create soap template for soap request

4.for Given WSDL I need to create soap template

which java wsdl library I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Soap UI itself is the best one for it. If you wan to do it using java try soapui library for the same.

```
        WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
        WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, "http://webservices.daehosting.com/services/TemperatureConversions.wso?WSDL");
        for (Operation operation : wsdls[0].getOperationList()) {
            WsdlOperation op = (WsdlOperation) operation;
            System.out.println(op.createRequest(true));
            System.out.println(op.createResponse(true));
    }
```

The dependency details can be found from pom [here](http://www.soapui.org/repository/eviware/). Jars can be directly downloaded from [here](http://www.soapui.org/repository/eviware/jars/).

Here is another [link](http://pritikaur23.wordpress.com/2013/06/16/saving-a-soapui-project-and-sending-requests-using-soapui-api/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the links,checking those